# How to play any waveform's audio in julia language?

Tags: julia

I have a sinusoid with length 5 seconds as below:

```
x=sin(0:.01:2*pi*500*5);
```

Now I would like to hear the audio of this waveform by giving a command similar as below:

```
playsound(x,samplingfrequency);
```

It will be useful for me if I could write this audio data to a wav or mp3 file. What is the library needed and the equivalent command in julia for this functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may play audio  with https://github.com/ssfrr/AudioIO.jl

And for write/read wav https://github.com/JuliaLang/Sound.jl/blob/master/src/Sound.jl

However at this time both modules are in early stage.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [WAV.jl](https://github.com/dancasimiro/wav.jl) to encode the data in a WAV file. You can install the package via the Julia package system:

```
Pkg.add("WAV")
```

Then, use the `wavwrite` function to create the file:

```
wavwrite(data, "example.wav", Fs=8000)
```

There is a function ([wavplay](https://github.com/dancasimiro/WAV.jl/blob/8ffcefc32aa986d155036aa536c0c5672bb189e4/src/wavplay.jl#L10)) buried in the WAV source code repository to play audio too, but it only works on Linux. I am waiting for someone to contribute windows and mac versions before I include it as part of an official version.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late here, but I also found [this page](https://github.com/svaksha/Julia.jl/blob/master/Hardware.md), which might be of use as well. It documents a series of libraries for dealing with hardware in Julia, and contains a surprisingly lengthy list for audio/video stuff.

Comment: Sadly, dead link :(