# How to play a sound in Julia

Tags: audio, julia

I'm programming in Julia and I would like to reproduce some simple audio, like single notes or similar.

I was wondering whether there is a way or a library to reproduce simple sounds. Is there anybody who know it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148160/how-to-play-any-waveforms-audio-in-julia-language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you need this for things like having a sound signal to let yourself know that your computations has finished this will work:

```
using WAV
y, fs = wavread(raw"C:\Windows\Media\Ring01.wav")
wavplay(y, fs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the reason. I’m using Mac, does your solution work also in this case?

Comment: I do not own a Mac. Maybe try it - there is a good chance it will work. Let me know!

Comment: I eventually used this solution: 
using WAV
fs = 7e3
t = 0.0:1/fs:prevfloat(0.3)
f = 8e2
y = sin.(2pi * f * t) * 0.1
wavplay(y, fs)
wavplay(y, fs)
wavplay(y, fs), which reproduce three sounds one after the others, using the library you suggested! It was easier instead of loading a wav file:)